# The Doctype declaration is coming in 2nd line while the first line is empty space

Tags: html, jsp, doctype

When i am doing view source of my webpage,

The Doctype declaration is coming in 2nd line while the first line is empty space.

How to remove that empty space in 1st line?

What are the pros and cons of it? Will it affect page performance any how?

Comment: Some very old browsers (that you shouldn't use any more) will have problems with whitespace above the DOCTYPE, yes. How are you creating your HTML? I assume it's not just a plain HTML file on the server?

Comment: It has been added as first line in my header.jsp

Comment: Oh... not familiar with JSP, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[Strip whitespace from jsp output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output)
[Whitespace before XML declaration from JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924284/whitespace-before-xml-declaration-from-jsp)
If those ideas don't help you then show us the first few lines of your JSP.